# Convert bool to number. Better Algorithm?

Tags: javascript

Recently, I interviewed in one company and received a test task:

```
Implement a function that accepts any data type and convert the boolean type (if any) to a numeric value.
Objects of any nesting level, arrays, strings, numbers, etc. can be used as parameters.
```

Example:

```js
booleanToInt('qwerty') // 'qwerty' 
booleanToInt(1) // 1 
booleanToInt(false) // 0 
booleanToInt(true) // 1 
booleanToInt([1, 'qwerty', false]) // [1, 'qwerty', 0] 
booleanToInt([1, 'qwerty', { a: true }]) // [1, 'qwerty', { a: 1 }] 
booleanToInt({ a: { b: true }, c: false, d: 'qwerty' }) // { a: { b: 1 }, c: 0, d: 'qwerty' }
```

I wrote my own implementation, but I was told that this is too complicated and a big solution. To my question, what and where can I optimize the answer was not given to me.

My decision:

```js
// Checking for an object
function isObject(value) {
  return typeof value === "object" && !Array.isArray(value) && value !== null;
}

// Transforming an object
function transformObject(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (isObject(obj[key])) {
      transformObject(obj[key]);
    } else if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
      transformArray(obj[key]);
    } else {
      obj[key] = transformStatic(obj[key]);
    }
  });
}

// Transforming the array
function transformArray(list) {
  list.forEach((item, i) => {
    if (isObject(item)) {
      transformObject(item);
    } else if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      transformArray(item);
    } else {
      list[i] = transformStatic(item);
    }
  });
}

// Transforming Static Types
function transformStatic(value) {
  let res = value;

  if (typeof value === "boolean") {
    res = +value;
  }

  return res;
}

// main function
function booleanToInt(value) {
  if (isObject(value)) {
    transformObject(value);
    return value;
  }

  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    transformArray(value);
    return value;
  }

  return transformStatic(value);
}

console.log(booleanToInt("qwerty")); // 'qwerty'
console.log(booleanToInt(1)); // 1
console.log(booleanToInt(false)); // 0
console.log(booleanToInt(true)); // 1

console.log(booleanToInt([1, "qwerty", false])); // [1, 'qwerty', 0]
console.log(booleanToInt([1, "qwerty", { a: true }])); //[1, 'qwerty', { a: 1 }]
```

[LIVE HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/3-zadanie-dhr1vb?file=/src/index.js:309-1736)

I wonder what other algorithm can come up with?
Perhaps it will be shorter and more concise?

Comment: Questions about optimizing running code is better asked at [codereview.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd simplify it to single function and use `for ... in`

```js
function booleanToInt(value) {
  if (typeof value === "boolean") return +value;
  if (typeof value === "object") for (const k in value) value[k] = booleanToInt(value[k]);
  return value;
}

console.log(booleanToInt("qwerty")); // 'qwerty'
console.log(booleanToInt(1)); // 1
console.log(booleanToInt(false)); // 0
console.log(booleanToInt(true)); // 1

console.log(booleanToInt([1, "qwerty", false])); // [1, 'qwerty', 0]
console.log(booleanToInt([1, "qwerty", { a: true }])); //[1, 'qwerty', { a: 1 }]
```